# The graphing in Apple's stock app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Is the graphing portion of Apple's "Stocks" iPhone application available to developers?

My guess would be that it is not. If I am right, on a rough scale on 0-100, how difficult would it be to reproduce? (I know this is a silly question, but anyway. Just want some idea.) Also, what framework do you think would be the most suitable for the reproduction? Core Animation? Notice especially how you can drag your finger across the charts when in landscape mode to see the prices on each data point. It's just way too cool.

Comment: There's even more to the graph in Stocks app than that.  Turn on VoiceOver in Accessibility, and the graph will talk to you about the data points.  No vision required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/core-plot/ is probably what you're looking for.

Comment: In particular, the AAPLot example application, which uses the `kCPStocksTheme`, a theme we made to replicate that of Apple's Stocks application.

Comment: The hooks are also there to respond to touch events on the plot itself, although I don't believe they are used for anything yet in any of the sample applicatinos.

Comment: Ok, nice. I guess I will look into Core Plot!

Answer (score 1):

There are several commercial tools for iOS charting, which can probably reproduce the chart you are looking for.

- [ShinobiControls](http://www.shinobicontrols.com) - which has many interactive features, as seen [in this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NxK1oE0vXog).
- [www.threedgraphics.com](http://www.threedgraphics.com)
- [iPhone Charting Library for iPhone Objective-C](http://www.keepedge.com/products/iphone_charting/)

***Full Disclosure** - I work for Scott Logic, which is the parent company of ShinobiControls*

Answer (score 0):

It's also worth checking out SciChart, which has an [ios financial chart control](https://www.scichart.com/ios-stock-charts/). 
[image]
It is a paid control, but in [performance tests](https://www.scichart.com/ios-chart-performance-comparison/) really outstrips competitors including paid and open source. Some by a mile.

It supports Objective-C, Swift2.2, Swift3 as well as Xamarin in the upcoming v2.x release.

You can now clone the [iOS Chart examples on Github](https://github.com/ABTSoftware/SciChart.iOS.Examples) and have a play around with the controls and see how we created the above example app!

***Full disclosure*** - I work for SciChart and am the tech lead on the project